# How to get PIDs connected to another PID's standard input/output/error?

Tags: bash, background-process

After something like `first_command | … | last_command &` `$!` is set to the PID of `last_command`. How can I find the other PIDs in this pipeline? Especially, is there a convenient way to find the PID of the second to last command? I can look in `/proc/$!/fd/0` and `grep` for the pipe number in `ls /proc/*/fd/1`, but that isn't exactly reliable.

Comment: Looks like [it has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652680/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-that-is-piped-to-another-process-in-bash).

Comment: @WeijunZhou I had only read as far as the two first solutions, but [the third looks like it would work without changing the commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907950/96588), which was what I was looking for.